# what's System.property means?

Tags: java

I would like to ask what's the use of System.property in this source code? I can't find exact answer.

```
public abstract class BaseIndexingTestCase extends TestCase {
protected String[] keywords = {"1", "2"};
protected String[] unindexed = {"Netherlands", "Italy"};
protected String[] unstored = {"Amsterdam has lots of bridges",
"Venice has lots of canals"};
protected String[] text = {"Amsterdam", "Venice"};
protected Directory dir;
protected void setUp() throws IOException {
String indexDir =
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "tmp") +
System.getProperty("file.separator") + "index-dir";
dir = FSDirectory.getDirectory(indexDir, true);
addDocuments(dir);
}
protected void addDocuments(Directory dir)
throws IOException {
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, getAnalyzer(),
true);
writer.setUseCompoundFile(isCompound());
for (int i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(Field.Keyword("id", keywords[i]));
doc.add(Field.UnIndexed("country", unindexed[i]));
doc.add(Field.UnStored("contents", unstored[i]));
doc.add(Field.Text("city", text[i]));
writer.addDocument(doc);
}
writer.optimize();
writer.close();
}
protected Analyzer getAnalyzer() {
return new SimpleAnalyzer();
}
protected boolean isCompound() {
return true;
}
}
```

this is the line that confuses me.

```
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "tmp") +
System.getProperty("file.separator") + "index-dir";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this

```
String indexDir =
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "tmp") +
System.getProperty("file.separator") + "index-dir";
```

creates a folder systemtempdir/index-dir or tmp/index-dir if no propertyentry for a temporary directory has been found.

Answer (score 2):

The [`System.getProperty(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) calls are there in order to get the `temp` dir of the OS:

- `java.io.tmpdir` is the temp dir
- `file.separator` is the OS-specific file separator - either `/` or `\`